# Measuring reverse recovery time of a diode

Tags: diodes, reverse-recovery

What is the exact formula for reverse recovery time of a diode? I've read a bunch of articles regarding this question, and each of them answers differently -- the time interval between peak negative current and its either 10, 15 or 20% value. What is the precise value of a said percentage?

Comment: What instruments do you have to measure it? For example, do you have an oscilloscope and a signal generator? Signal generator is useful for generating impulse with short raise/fall-time for reverse voltage.

Comment: I've found simulation to be quite a useful tool for determining trr in the specific circuit of application.

Comment: I use oscilloscope and pulse generator for measurments.

Comment: It's not a well defined parameter. All of the end-point figures you've mentioned are used, by different sources. In practice it doesn't matter too much which you use. They are all significant, and much smaller than the peak.

Comment: So its not as important as I thought whether 10% or 25% of the peak negative current is chosen as the end point?